# How to archive and versionize a filesystem for Windows and MacOSX?

Tags: windows, macos, git, tags

**The problem:**
On a MacOSX-Snow Leopard-Server is a directory structure holding project directories containing (mostly large binary) files.
The clients accessing these files via common network file access are Windows7 and MacOSX Snow Leopard.

**The requirements:**
It's necessary to have a timestamp on each file to document when the file has come in (the modification date is too vague and can be changed by accident). Like a file tag that contains just the date (or a string).
The files should be versioned like with git. So if a new version comes in the old one goes to the repository.
The files should be accessible by common network access - so it's a no-go to checkout a project by git e.g. just to look into it. That's a very important point.

**My thoughts so far:**
I already thought about using git for this. The server directory is a git working copy (no public repository server). This means the files remain accessible through the common file system and new files can be committed and therefore would get a timestamp when they have been created.

**There are two downsides though:**
git seems to be not the best solution for archiving and handling binary files. And problems evolve when the files have special characters in them (like German Umlauts), especially on Windows (msysgit).

I already found some git extensions like [git-media](https://github.com/schacon/git-media) but it seems they are not supported by the different git GUIs that exist (Tower on Mac or TortoiseGIT on Windows).

Does anyone know how this can be solved? Is there a filesystem that supports this and runs on Windows and Mac?

Answer (score 1):

As a versioning system, good old **CVS** could do the job, I reckon. In CVS you can mark files as binary on check-in. GUIs exist for Windows and for Mac.

Comment: But what's the advantage compared to git?